# How to get only duplicate keys at json via jq?

Tags: json, unique, jq

I'm read all answers at stackoverflow and jq manual but can't find and understand what options need to use to solve next task:

> jq '.result[] | "\(.name) \(.content)"' :

```
"test.mydomain.com 123.123.123.123"
"static.mydomain.com 124.124.124.124"
"static.mydomain.com 124.124.124.128"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.125"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.126"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.127"
```

Need to get from this list only duplicates per first value:

```
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.125"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.126"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.127"
"static.mydomain.com 124.124.124.124"
"static.mydomain.com 124.124.124.128"
```

Sorry about Your time

Best regards

Comment: is this `"test.mydomain.com 123.123.123.123"` a key value item of your json object? If yes so shouldn't be like this: `"test.mydomain.com":"123.123.123.123"`?

Comment: hi, thank for response at this example \(.name) \(.content) both keys from one array result. At bashscript output it looks like I wrote upper

Answer (score 3):

Let's make this easy by using a generic utility function (suitable perhaps for your standard jq library):

```
# In this formulation, f must either always evaluate to a string or always to an integer
# it being understood that negative integers might be problematic
def aggregate_by(f; g):
  reduce .[] as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);
```

Using the -s ("slurp") option, the task can now be broken down into the following steps:

```
map(split(" "))
| aggregate_by(.[0]; .[1])
| with_entries(select(.value|length > 1))
| to_entries[]
| .key as $k | .value[] | [$k, .]
| join(" ")
```

### Output (based on original example)

```
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.125"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.126"
```

### Output (based on revised example)

```
"static.mydomain.com 124.124.124.124"
"static.mydomain.com 124.124.124.128"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.125"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.126"
"mydomain.com 125.125.125.127"
```

Comment: Thanks this resolve upper example but can it resolve example where 3 duplicates as first value?

Comment: Yes, but your question is a bit vague. I would suggest modifying your Q (e.g. by adding another example) to make your requirements clearer.

Comment: Edit example, please get a suggest if it easier to solve with bash script

Comment: @gremlintv2 - The script already given passes the new test case as well!!!

Comment: Thanks so what i'm doing wrong: .result[] | "\\(.name) \'(.content)"| map(split(" ")) | aggregate_by(.[0]; .[1]) | with_entries(select(.value|length > 1)) | to_entries[] | .key as $k | .value[] | [$k, .] | join(" ")   output: jq: 1 compile error

Comment: You’ll find debugging easier if you put the jq program into a multi-line file. There are several obvious problems with your combined program, esp. the stray single-quote. Also, it is a bit silly to create a string only to have to parse it again.